# allow blank selection with kendoDropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I want to add a blank selection item for KendoUi dropdownlist. I followed the same as mentioned in the below link.

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/dropdownlist/how-to-allow-blank-selection-with-kendodropdownlist.aspx

But if I call the below in document.ready event,

```
$("#ddl").data("kendoDropDownList").one("open", function() {
            $(this.ul[0].firstChild).html(" ");
});
```

I get error 'one' is null or undefined error. I have added the required reference files. What might be causing this? Is there any other way to add blank selection option?

I have defined the combobox as below in my mvc view.

```
<span class="list">
   @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
   .Name("facility").Events(events => events.Change("facilityChange"))
   .OptionLabel(" ")
   .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("_GetFacilitiesForComboBox", "SuccessionInfo")))
   .DataTextField("FacilityName")
   .DataValueField("FacilityId")
   .Value(Model.NextJobFacilityId.ToString())
   .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
    )
 </span>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved it by adding css

```
.k-popup .k-list .k-item {
    min-height: 1.8em;
}
```

Reference - http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/dropdownlist/empty-selectitems-do-no-display-correctly.aspx